# mysql workbench modify stored procedure on remote server

Tags: mysql, procedure, workbench

I'm trying to modify stored procedures in a remote server. The user@% account has `CREATE PROCEDURE`, `ALTER PROCEDURE`, and `EXECUTE` permissions on the relevant database.

I am not getting any error or rejection from the remote server, only success notifications. However, when opening the remote server's phpmyadmin and looking at the procedure, its code is unmodified.

I am using mysql workbitch 5.2.38, connecting to mysql server 5.1.18. I tried connecting via CLI and running a test, and here's what i got:

```
mysql> drop procedure benchmark_1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create procedure benchmark_1 () begin end;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

i can connect just fine. standard queries execute and update data just fine, and stored procedure drops and create statements work just fine, but the changes are not persisting on the server despite the server returning success for the operation.

Comment: can you not connect to the remote with workbench? if you can you should be able to alter the procedure directly... Do take note of which user is involved - you can have multiple procedures of the same name defined by different users.

Comment: yeah, connection is fine, and i am aware of which user to edit. imma post this on mysqls forums and see what they think...

Comment: did you find the solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

this solved the issue for me.

```
grant show_routine on *.* to <MYUSER>;
```

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71313234)