# Can't open stored procedures with MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL database hosted on Dreamhost. I've defined a single user for that database, with full rights.

I've just started using MySQL Workbench. I had no trouble connecting to the database. But when I try to view the contents of stored procedures that I created using the web client provided by Dreamhost, I get nothing. By nothing, I mean that right-click | Send to SQL Editor | Create statement does nothing. No new tab, no error message, nothing. Ditto for right-click | Send to SQL Editor | Procedure Call. Ditto when clicking the wrench or lightning icons.

Based on something I found online, it appears to be a rights issue. But when I choose Server | Users and Privileges to try to fix it, I get this message:

"The account you are currently using does not have sufficient privileges to make changes to MySQL users and privileges."

How can that be when there's only one user and that user has all rights?

Comment: I would advise contacting DreamHost directly.

Comment: Does `SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS;` return anything?

Comment: SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS; shows all SPs, both those I created on Dreamhost and those I created with MySQL Workbench. The only visible differences are in definer, character set client and collation connection. For definer, the same user name appears for all, but the "@ipaddress" part is different (as you'd expect, I think).

Answer (score 4):

For me although I granted full privilege on that database, I still cannot view it's store procedure.

So I have to run this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO yourusername@'%';
```

Problem solved !!

Answer (score 1):

On mysql 8.0.20+ run this to give a user permission to view the procedure:

```
grant show_routine on *.* to <MYUSER>;
```

Run this to give the user permission to edit and run procedures:

```
grant execute, create routine, alter routine on <MYDB>.* to <MYUSER>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the immediate problem by opening the SP in phpAdmin on the Dreamhost site and cutting and pasting the code into MySQL Workbench, recreating the SP from there. That does seem, however, to keep me from editing the SP on Dreamhost. Clearly something's still wrong, but I can move forward.